# How do I convert 48V to 3.3V?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, wall-wart

What is the proper method or device to convert 48V to 3.3V?  Total current consumption at 3.3V would be from 60mA to 150mA.

I found several voltage regulators, but they do not have the required capacity (7W, 45V * .15A).

Likewise I tried doing it with voltage dividers but the capacity is likewise too small.

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic for this site, I would suggest going to webench.ti.com and using the that tool to input your requirements.  It will give you lots of options.  I believe ADI and Maxim have similar tools as well.

Comment: You need to use a buck converter, which will only need to dissipate on the order of 50-100mW.

Comment: Are you saying that it will pull up to 150mA @ 48V? Or 150mA at 3.3V?

Comment: @JohnD, I don't think this is a shopping question.  He has a device which isn't going to work for him, and needs to know alternative devices that might be more suitable.  In his case, a buck converter.

Comment: @MarkHarrison Fair enough, I retracted my close vote.

Comment: thanks for info, I will use buck converter for this.

Comment: We desperately need a community wiki for "How to convert X to Y voltage." There are many duplicates of this with different numbers in place of the variables.

Comment: I couldn't find a general/basic Q&A on this topic, so I created a community wiki for it. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/501176/2028

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've observed, a voltage regulator won't work for the power levels you're working with.

A [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) is the device you're looking for, it's used to step down DC voltage.  It's the opposite of a Boost converter, which is used to step up DC voltage.

Comment: thanks got it, will use buck converter for this.

Comment: Good luck, and welcome to the EE Stack!